# Do I need cross validation?

Tags: regression

Let's say i have a dataset that contains time series object(column). In my case I have stock price data, and i need to predict next day price using non-linear regression model. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it to build a model, but without it, you will have no idea of how well your model can be expected to perform on new data. The purpose of cross validation is to provide an unbiased estimate of the performance of your model-building process, by testing it on data that was not used to build the model. The performance of your model measured on the training data can be a wildly over-optimistic measure of performance. In the most extreme case your algorithm can just memorize the training data and spit out the right answer using a lookup table, but would utterly fail when confronted by any new data point that wasn't in the training set.

Comment: I've just heard that for time series it's better to use nested cross-validation. Am i right ?

Comment: @AndrewAbugazalekh, what is better?